# How to generate Registration controller of devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have setup Devise, I have set up the below code in my user.rb file

```
  def self.create_auto_password
    generated_password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
    self.create(password: generated_password, password_confirmation: generated_password)
  end
```

I then tried to generate a registrations controller by running

`rails generate devise:controllers -c registrations`

and a few other variations but it won't generate... what is the correct command to create a registrations controller in Devise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just create the controller manually and make it inherit from Devise. For example:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # Override the action you want here.
end
```

This controller should live in app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb

And mention it in your routes.

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
```

And if you want to only generate it by command than you need to add device gem from master branch because that generator is present on that branch.

```
gem 'devise', git: 'https://github.com/plataformatec/devise'
```

As mention on [github_issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3222#issuecomment-56727520)

Answer (score 1):

The command you are using has a typo. It should be as shown below:

```rb
rails generate devise:controllers users -c=sessions
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

To generate Devise registration controller only for users use:

```
rails g devise:controllers users -c=registrations
```

o/p:
[image]

To generate all devise controllers for users use:

```
rails g devise:controllers users
```

o/p:
[image]

Now for actually start using you generated devise controllers modify routes.rb according to generated controller Ex:

for registration do

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
      registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
```

and for registrations and sessions do:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
      registrations: 'users/registrations',
      sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }
```

Comment: The `rails d` should be a `rails g`, else it deletes previously generated controllers if there are any.

Comment: I think the uploaded images ought to be displayed in the opposite order